# turning a validate function from if statements to a switch statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have a form in react that I'm refactoring. I'm going to move most of the state and logic to the parent, because the parent state will be updated with the form result... but I was going to refactor before and can't seem to get a switch statement to work. I was told it would help performance in the long run.

The Validate function is where I'm trying to add a switch statement.

```
 import React from 'react'
    import styles from './style.addLibForm.css'

class AddLibForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
            input: {
                title: "",
                content: "",
                imgURL: ""
            },
            blurred: {
                title: false,
                content: false,
                imgURL: ""
            },
            formIsDisplayed: this.props.toggle
        };
      }


handleInputChange(newPartialInput) {

  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    input: {
      ...state.input,
      ...newPartialInput
    }
  }))

}

handleBlur(fieldName) {
this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    blurred: {
        ...state.blurred,
        [fieldName]: true
      }
  }))
}

***//TURN INTO SWITCH STATEMENT!***
validate() {
    const errors = {};
    const {input} = this.state;

    if (!input.title) {
        errors.title = 'Title is required';
    } //validate email

    if (!input.content) {
        errors.content = 'Content is required';
    }

    if (!input.imgURL) {
        errors.imgURL = 'Image URL is required';
    }
    console.log(Object.keys(errors).length === 0);
    return {
        errors,
        isValid: Object.keys(errors).length === 0
    };
}


render() {
  const {input, blurred} = this.state;
  const {errors, isValid} = this.validate();


  return (

    <div className="flex">
      <form
        className={styles.column}
        onSubmit={(e) =>
          { e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({})
            return console.log(this.state.input);
            }}>

        <h2> Add a library! </h2>


          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              className={styles.right}
              name="title"
              type="text"
              value={input.title}
              onBlur={() => this.handleBlur('title')}
              onChange={e => this.handleInputChange({title: e.target.value})}/>
          </label>
          <br/>



          <label>
            Content:
            <input
              className={styles.right}
              name="content"
              type="text"
              value={input.content}
              onBlur={() => this.handleBlur('content')}
              onChange={e => this.handleInputChange({content: e.target.value})}/>
          </label>
          <br/>


          <label>
            Image URL:
            <input
              className={styles.right}
              name="imgURL"
              type="text"
              value={input.imgURL}
              onBlur={() => this.handleBlur('imgURL')}
              onChange={e => this.handleInputChange({imgURL: e.target.value})}/>
          </label>
          <br/>

        <p>
            <input className={styles.button} type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!isValid}/>
        </p>

        {/* CSS THESE TO BE INLINE WITH INPUTS */}
        <br/>
        {blurred.content && !!errors.content && <span>{errors.content}</span>}

        <br/>
        {blurred.title && !!errors.title && <span>{errors.title}</span>}
        <br/>
        {blurred.imgURL && !!errors.imgURL && <span>{errors.imgURL}</span>}

      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
  }

export default AddLibForm
```

I've was putting the switch statement inside the validate function. I tried inputs, errors, this.state.input, this.state.errors, {input}... what am I missing?

Comment: why do you want to use a switch statement? I don't see where it is necessary.

Comment: You can't reproduce the same functionality with a single switch. Whoever told you it would help with performance clearly didn't look at the code beforehand. This is the simplest and most efficient way to do what the code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: RAD, I'll take this down. I was told by a pretty smart dude I assumed, but he might have not looked at the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch statement makes most sense when you need to compare one variable with different values

````
if(x === 1){
//...
} else if(x === 2) {
//...
} else if(x === 3) {
//...
} else {} {
//...
}```
````

=>

```
switch (x) { 
  case 1: 
  //... 
  break;
  case 2: 
  //... 
  break;
  case 3: 
  //... 
  break;
  default: 
  //...
}
```

since it clearly expresses this "1 variable to many values" mapping condition.

In your case though you don't compare one var to many values, you simply check multiple variables for existence, i.e. semantically compare them with a truthy value, so switch will not make much sense.

It's better to leave as is since all these ifs are checking different conditions and are still pretty readable.

Overall you can check [this article](https://sergeyski.com/cyclomatic-complexity-refactoring-tips/) for a more verbose directions on approaching condition handling more efficiently.